# How can I find POS from given SOP?

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

Here are the sets of POS

1. C + B’D
2. (AC) + (B’CD) + (AB’D)
3. (BC) + (A’CD’) + (A’B’C’D)
4. (BC) + (ACD’)
5. (B’C) + (A’CD’) + (ACD)

This (') stand for NOT.
Please help!

Comment: Are POS and SOP alternative terms to DNF and CNF?

Comment: @GitGud No sir, could you please check my answers below?

Comment: If you're just meant to negate the given statements, then your answer is mostly correct. You have a typo in the last one.You typed $B'$ instead of $C'$.

Comment: I really have no idea what is going on here, what is SOP, POS? What are $A,B,C$ and $D$?

Comment: @GitGud Thank you sir!

Comment: @GitGud yes: CNF = POS = "product of sums", DNF = SOP = "sum of products".

Comment: The key here is to note that "addition" distributes over "multiplication" in this context.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the answers I have got. Is this correct?

1. (C’) (B+D’)
2. (A’+C’) (B+C’+D’) (A’+B+D’)
3. (B’+C’) (A+C’+D) (A+B+C+D’)
4. (B’+C’) (A’+C’+D)
5. (B+C’) (A+C’+D) (A’+C’+D’)

Comment: These statements are the negations of what you were given.  So, for example,
$$
(C')(B+D') = (C + B'D)'
$$
I have a feeling that this isn't what you were going for.